# C++ vs. C# calculation (wrong result)

Tags: c#, c++, math

I have a little problem;

I have this C++ calculation:

```
int main(unsigned long pass){

char name[50];

cout << "Enter username please: " << endl << endl;
gets_s(name);
cout << "\n";

pass = strlen(name);
pass = pass * 3;
pass = pass << 2;
pass = pow(pass, 3.0);
pass = pass + 23;
pass = pass + (pass * 708224);

cout << "Your generated serial: " << +pass << endl << endl;

system("pause");}
```

This gives me the working code for a 3 char username.

This is my C# calculation.

```
private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pass = txt_user.TextLength;           
        pass = pass * 3;
        pass = pass << 2;
        pass = pass * pass * pass;
        pass = pass + 23;
        pass = pass + (pass * 708224);

        txt_serial.Text = pass.ToString();
    }
```

This gives me the wrong code for the exact same username..

What is strange is that the calculation on both gives me the same result until this line:

```
pass = pass + (pass * 708224);
```

after this calculation C# gives me the wrong result.

c++ result: `2994463703` (correct)

c# result: `33059234775` (wrong)

I hope someone can explain this.

Comment: What is the data type of `pass` in C# code? This could be a problem with using the wrong size of variable and it wrapping.

Comment: The C++ calc is wrong.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of `pass` in your C# code so it's hard to be sure, but from the looks of things, your "right" answer depends on its being a 32-bit type, and it's something larger than that.

Comment: If you reverse the order of operations (which is *really* easy with this "algorithm"), you find that the C# result of `33059234775` correctly reverses to `3`. The C++ result, however, does not. I would investigate the C++ `pow(pass, 3.0)` line.

Comment: both are declared as a "long".

thanks for ur answer but thats somehow strange cuz as said the result in c++ gets accepted as a working password and the one in c# doesnt work lol

Comment: @DennIs PS: No it's not. Do the math by hand. `3*3=9`, `9<<2=36`, `36*36*36=46,656`, `46,656+23=46,679`, `46,679+(46,679*708224)=33,059,234,775`. Oh look, this *by hand* result is the same as the C# result. Your C++ is wrong. Probably on the line I indicated. (Or in data-type.)

Comment: @DennIs If your C++ value is what was used to calculate the *original password* then that would be why.

Comment: i now changed the pow function to: pass = pass * pass * pass and it gives shows me the same result as before. any other ideas whats wrong?

Comment: @DennIs Have you even **attempted** to debug it? Step through the programmes calculation *line-by-line*, and compare what value is there vs what should be. (I gave you all the answers above.) And do note: I recommend you *secure* this value as anyone who has the source (everyone) can easily reverse the steps.

Comment: its an external program this code is used for. and thats the algorithm i got out of it. i just dont understand why the c++ code is wrong (when calculated manually) but gets accepted and the c# code (which is correct) doesnt work at all

Comment: long in C# is 64 bit. Long in C++ may be 32 or 64 bit. 33,059,234,775 is way out of range for a 32 bit long.

Comment: You understand that `pow(pass, 3.0);` returns a `double` right? If you are using C11, try just putting `pow(pass, 3L);` and see if it works.

Comment: Also, @user4581301 is spot on: in a 32-bit, unsigned, environment, that value would be interpreted as `2,994,463,703`. You should *really* improve this "algorithm."

Comment: as said this is a external program and is not from me. it was coded for testing purpose. i just debugged both and they give back the same result after this calculation is done (pass = pass + (pass * 708224).
thats where they seperate. this has to be some big luck that the wrong calculation is actually working :o

i guess the one who coded this made the same mistake somewhere and thats why its working

Answer (score 2):

So, there are three (at least) underlying issues here.

1. This algorithm grows exponentially, and offers **no** protection against anything. It is easily reversible and does not attempt to secure the input.
2. The `pow(pass, 3.0)` method is **going** to return a `double`.
3. The `long` datatype (in C++) is **not always** 64-bits. It **can be** 32-bit.

If we ignore the first point, and skip to two and three, there are two potential issues:

1. When the `pow(pass, 3.0)` line gets hit, it *may not always* return the same value, due to floating-point error. (Now, I don't suspect this is a major issue in your code, but you fail to take it into account.)
2. When the `pass + (pass * 708224)` line (which can be rewritten as `pass * 708225` fyi) gets hit, on a 32-bit C++ environment it will **silently overflow** to the value `2,994,463,703`, which just so happens to be your C++ result.

So, how do you fix this?

Fix that algorithm. As it stands, you can easily build a lookup table of potential values.

```
Input (pass)  Output
1             1,240,154,505
2             9,806,791,575
3             33,059,234,775
4             78,340,308,375
5             152,992,889,175
etc.          etc.
```

Now, the issue here is not that these numbers are *always* going to be the same, that's generally expected. The issue is that the **only** value which actually fits within an `Int32` is the first one. As soon as the second character is calculated, it's outside the potential range. And if you are going to be doing this in C++, you should really try to make sure you avoid `long` data-types. They are **not always** guaranteed to be 64-bits.

If you need a *serial* or *hash* (as we call them in the real-world), I recommend you look at `md5`, `sha1/2`, or any other hash algorithm. (All three mentioned here are built into .NET, should be easy enough to get them for C++.)

### How can I tell if my C++ environment supports 64-bit `unsigned long` variables?

Easy, seed a `unsigned long` value with the maximum value for an `unsigned int` (`4,294,967,295`), add one to it, and check if the value is less than 1.

```
unsigned long test = 4294967295;
test = test + 1;
bool longIs64Bits = test > 0;
```

The result should be either `true`, or `false`. If `true`, then you have a 64-bit `unsigned long` type. If `false`, then you don't.

### What if I really need 64-bit numbers?

Fortunately, C++ also provides a `long long` variable type. (As well as `unsigned long long`.) Note: these data-type sizes can vary, but will be **no less than** 64-bits.

```
unsigned long long test = 4294967295;
test = test + 1;
bool longLongIs64Bits = test > 0;
```

The preceding snippet should **always** be true.

Lastly, there is also `uint64_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`. This is guaranteed to be 64-bits. It's part of the C99 spec, and C++11 spec, though I cannot vouch for support of it.

Comment: thank for ur answer. yes, the main purpose of this program was to reverse it, thats why it has a poor security. i guess, if the program wouldve been coded in c# then my c# result would work. its coded in c++ so i think it encounters the same problem as mine and therefore the wrong code is actually working. thanks alot!

Comment: You *can still* make a similar algorithm that is reversible, but smaller. Change the `708224` to a **much** smaller number.

Comment: thanks. i think i recode it fast since i have no source and test some things. but thanks alot for ur help!

Comment: @EBrown FYI if you use a `long long` it is guaranteed to be a minimum of 64bits.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah yes, I forgot about that. (It's been years since I've done C++.) Going to update my answer now.

Comment: @NathanOliver Also, there is always `uint64_t` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: uint64_t was formally borged from C in C++11. You should be able to expect it as standard on PCs by now. Embedded... Not so much.

Answer (score 0):

EBrown is dead right that the C++ code need serious rethinking, but if the C++ code is legacy and you can't change it, the best you can do is duplicate the bugs in the C# version.

Use `uint` instead of `long` in the c# version to trigger the unsigned 32 bit overflow.

You can't reliably duplicate the double rounding error. Use `Math.pow` and pray it never comes up.

Edit:
Addendum: Friends don't let friends roll their own crypto.

Comment: I always pray when I use `Math.Pow`.

Comment: also thanks to you. i triggered the overflow and gives the same result as in c++.

Comment: Also, fortunately for him, he should never run into the floating-point error, as he is not using quantities that could ever have decimals. (His numbers are integers, risen to a whole-power.) That said, C++ is an awfully odd language and who knows if it will ever come up.